# Watching a Vue.js computed property returns looping data in the console

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, algolia, computed-properties

When I am watching the distance computed property below, that data returned is constant rather than just when the data is changed.

Is this meant to happen because I am setting then watching or is there an error? I want to watch and then reformat some the of outputted data when the computed property is changed by the user.

```
computed: {
      distance: {
        get: function() {
          let location = parseFloat(this.radius_search.lat) + ', ' + parseFloat(this.radius_search.lng);
          return this.search_store.queryParameters = { aroundLatLng: location, aroundRadius: this.radiusToMetres };
        },
        set(value) {
          return this.search_store.queryParameters = this.distance;
        },

      },

      radiusToMetres(){
        return this.radius * 1600;
      },

   },
        watch: {
          distance: function(value) {
                console.log(value);
          },

      },
```

I have a screen shot of the console output below.

[image]

Comment: It is because you are setting and resetting the data in your loop which I think is how the getter/setter works and the watcher detects it and is showing you the list

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a value in a getter, which is a bad practice. Getters should have no side effects.

In particular, you are creating a new object and assigning it to the return value, which is causing the loop: `distance` gets a new value every time it is looked at, and every time it gets a new value, its dependencies (like your watcher) are looking at it.